# SQL find rows not having duplicate column values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a query

```
select * from circuit where y ='b';
```

I get the following result

```
x       |  location_a  | location_b  | y  
-----------------------------------------
1232    |     mexico   |  usa        | b
1232    |     mexico   |  usa        | b
1232    |     brasil   |  usa        | b
9999    |     brasil   |  usa        | b
```

I need to find out the `x` that has no repeated location_a and location_b. In this case the following data has to be printed.

```
1232    |     brasil   |  usa        | b
9999    |     brasil   |  usa        | b
```

I'm using Oracle 10g. Please let me know if that is possible. (distinct/group by will remove duplicates but will still keep the one row which I do not need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytic functions to count the matches and then filter:

```
select x, location_a, location_b, y
from (select c.*,
             count(*) over (partition by x, location_a, location_b) as cnt
      from circuit
     ) c
where cnt = 1;
```

EDIT:

The `over` clause introduces an analytic functions.  To really understand them, you can start with the documentation (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)).  What this particular function does is assign a value to each row in the result set.  The value is the number of rows where `x`, `location_a`, and `location_b` have the same value as the row in question.  For your data, it would assign:

```
x       |  location_a  | location_b  | y  | cnt 
-----------------------------------------------
1232    |     mexico   |  usa        | b  |  2
1232    |     mexico   |  usa        | b  |  2
1232    |     brasil   |  usa        | b  |  1
9999    |     brasil   |  usa        | b  |  1
```

The first two rows have a "2" because there are two rows with 1232/mexico/usa.  The last two have a 1 because their triplets are unique.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Could you please explain what this count(*) over 9... has done here so I can use it in the future.

Comment: Learnt something new today. Thanks Gordon.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and to remove duplicates add condition: `having count(*) = 1`:

```
select x, location_a, location_b
 from circuit
 where y ='b'
 group by x, location_a, location_b
 having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: I like your answer. I feel stupid of not using having clause now. Thanks again!